# Visual basic - beginning program code

Tags: vb.net

My output is always 14.95 for package A..everything else seems to be working fine.

For the program I need to:

An internet service provicer offers 3 subscriptions packages to its customers, plus a discount for nonprofit organizations

- packaga A: 10 hours of access for $9.95 per month. Additional  are $2.00 per hour.
- package B: 20 Hours of access for $14.95 per month. Additional  are $1.00 per
- package C: Unlimited access for $19.95 per month
- Nonprofit Organizations: if user selects the nonprofit organization check box a 20
  % discount should be deducted from the final charges.
  input validation": the number if hours used in a month cannot exceed 744.. the value must be numeric

**btnCalc_Click**

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        'Declare variables and constant

        Dim decTotal As Decimal
        Dim intHours As Integer
        Const decNonProfit As Decimal = 0.8D
     Try

            intHours = CInt(txtHoursUsed.Text)

            If CInt(txtHoursUsed.Text) > 744 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Monthly Hours Can't Exceed 744")
                txtHoursUsed.Text = String.Empty
                lblTotalDue.Text = String.Empty
            End If

            'Calculate A Package Total without discount
            If radPackageA.Checked = True And intHours > 10 Then
                decTotal = (9.95 + ((intHours - 10) * 2))
            ElseIf intHours <= 10 Then
                decTotal = 9.95
            End If

            'Calculate B Package Total without discount
            If radPackageB.Checked = True And intHours > 20 Then
                decTotal = (14.95 + ((intHours - 20) * 1))
            ElseIf intHours <= 20 Then
                decTotal = 14.95
            End If

            'Calculate C Package Total without discount
            If radPackageC.Checked = True Then
                decTotal = 19.95
            End If

            'Calculate Total for packages if Nonprofit is checked
            If chkNonProfit.Checked = True Then
                decTotal = decTotal * decNonProfit

            End If

            'Show total due
            lblTotalDue.Text = decTotal.ToString("c")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Input Error")

        End Try

    End Sub
```

**btnClear_Click**

```
    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        radPackageA.Checked = False
        radPackageB.Checked = False
        radPackageC.Checked = False
        chkNonProfit.Checked = False
        lblTotalDue.Text = String.Empty
        txtHoursUsed.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub
```

**btnExit_Click**

```
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: I can't found anything wrong with your code. Could it be that you named package A `radPackageB` and package B `radPackageA`?

Comment: Package A output isn't working properly..ex. if package A is checked and I put in 5 for hours output is 14.95 instead of 9.95..if I put 20 in the text box it gives 14.95.. It gives 14.95 for all.  All the other package input/outputs are working.

Comment: show us your front end code

Comment: Doesn't seem to be it..I'll keep checking. Thanks though

Comment: Can you debug and see what is being run?

Comment: What is happening is that when radPackageB is not checked it is setting decTotal to 14.95. See my answer.

Comment: @MarkHall You're right, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose your entire conditional in your selection check. What is happening is that your false condition is always being run when repackageB.Checked is false.

```
            'Calculate A Package Total without discount
            If radPackageA.Checked Then
                If intHours > 10 Then
                    decTotal = (9.95 + ((intHours - 10) * 2))
                ElseIf intHours <= 10 Then
                    decTotal = 9.95
                End If
            End If

            'Calculate B Package Total without discount
            If radPackageB.Checked Then
                If intHours > 20 Then
                    decTotal = (14.95 + ((intHours - 20) * 1))
                ElseIf intHours <= 20 Then
                    decTotal = 14.95
                End If
            End If

            'Calculate C Package Total without discount
            If radPackageC.Checked Then
                decTotal = 19.95
            End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `ElseIf` to bifurcate the conditions in a wrong way.
Following your code you'll get `dectTotal = 14.95` everytime `radPackageB.Checked = False` and `intHours <= 20`

It should be like this:

```
        If radPackageB.Checked Then
            If intHours > 20 Then
                decTotal = (14.95 + ((intHours - 20) * 1))
            ElseIf intHours <= 20 Then
                decTotal = 14.95
            End If
        End If
```

So feel free to accept Mark's answer